# What is happening?

Tags: meditation

Sometimes when I meditate it feels like I completely lose all awareness of where I am and what I'm doing. Its like I blink and the hour has gone. I don't remember anything. It's like a blackout. I'm not sure if it's a good or a bad thing?

Comment: Did you fall asleep?

Comment: It is the opposite of everything that meditation is supposed to be- meditation (in buddhism) can be broadly put in 2 categories- awareness and analytical. Analytical requires awareness. Thus, to not have awareness at all, in the context of your question, is a bad thing.

Comment: What do you try to do when you meditate?

Comment: No it wasn't sleep. I think maybe I experienced anatta. Completely lost all sense of self and boundaries. Just disappeared. It feels really nice.

Comment: Giving you benefit of doubt I assume you aren't lying, just want to ask can you hear surrounding noises? If a mosquito bites you in that state do you feel itching? If your answers are negative then stop doing it now similar case happened with Swami Vivekananda he was meditating when he left his body.

Comment: Try changing your meditation style, like point meditation. Meditate on a single point for a time and see if the same things happen there too.

Answer (score 1):

It could be fruition. Compare Daniel Ingram's description:

> Fruition (phala in Pali) is the fruit of all the meditator’s hard
> work, the first attainment of ultimate reality, emptiness, nirvana,
> nibbana, ultimate potential, or whatever extrapolative and relatively
> inaccurate name you wish to call something utterly non-sensate. In
> this non-state, there is absolutely no time, no space, no reference
> point, no experience, no mind, no consciousness, no awareness, no
> background, no foreground, no nothingness, no somethingness, no body,
> no this, no that, no unity, no duality, and no anything else.
> “Reality” stops cold and then reappears.
>
> Thus, this is impossible to comprehend, as it goes completely and
> utterly beyond the rational mind and the universe. In “external time”
> (if we were observing the meditator) this stage typically lasts only
> an instant (though the question of “duration” will be addressed
> below). It is like an utter discontinuity of the space-time continuum
> with nothing in the unfindable gap, exactly like what happens when
> someone edits out a frame or sequence of frames of a movie. It is not
> that you see a blank screen for a while where they edited the frames
> out, instead that part of the movie is just not there.

The book *[Mastering the Core Teachings of the Buddha](https://www.mctb.org/mctb2/)* gives a lot more detail and some criteria by which to assess what kind of experience you had.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like falling asleep. This hindrance to meditation is called '*sloth & torpor*'.

> Any sloth is a hindrance. Any drowsiness is a hindrance. Thus what comes under the heading of ‘the hindrance of sloth & drowsiness’ becomes, by means of this exposition, twofold.
>
> [SN 46.52](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/SN/SN46_52.html)

> On any occasion the mind is sluggish, that is the wrong time to develop calm as a factor for awakening, concentration as a factor for awakening, equanimity as a factor for awakening. Why is that? The sluggish mind is hard to raise up by those mental qualities.
>
> On any occasion when the mind is sluggish, that is the right time to develop analysis of qualities as a factor for awakening, persistence as a factor for awakening, rapture as a factor for awakening. Why is that? The sluggish mind is easy to raise up by those mental qualities. Just as if a man, wanting to make a small fire blaze up, were to place dry grass in it, dry cow dung, & dry sticks; were to blow on it with his mouth and not smother it with dust.
>
> [AN 46.53](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn46/sn46.053.than.html)

Comment: But I don't think it is is sleeping as I'm sitting up and not nodding etc. I know when I'm falling asleep because my head falls forward